# How to change the zoom level of Google maps programmatically?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
function displayMapAndClick ()
    {
        var latlng    = new google.maps.LatLng (29.0167, 77.3833);
        var myOptions = 
        {
            zoom:zm,
            center:latlng,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map (document.getElementById ("map"), myOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap (map); 
    }
```

Where `zm`  is a global variable set to default `7`.

Now, I wish to change the zoom level of this map thorough this program.

What is the way to do that without re-initializing the map, or is re-initializing the map compulsory?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use the `setZoom()` method from the [`google.maps.Map`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) class.

```
var mapOptions = {
  /* Initial zoom level */
  zoom: 8
  ...
};
map = new google.maps.Map(..., mapOptions);
/* Change zoom level to 12  */
map.setZoom(12);
```

Answer (score 18):

In addition to Alexanders' sollution: I had the same problem, but the above didn't work for me in all browsers because sometimes the map.setZoom() is executed before the map is done loading.

Wrapping the function like this will make it work always:

```
...
map = new google.maps.Map(..., mapOptions);
/* Change zoom level to 12  */
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
  map.setZoom(12);
});
```

Comment: wrapping in an event listener as @publicJorn explained was what worked for me. thank you

Comment: This is the one that worked for me, as I was making a change to the map object after the map was loaded on the page. Thank you!